# HTML & CSS: row in colum in the table

Tags: html, css

I am creating a table but I am having trouble in the last panel (Condition). I want the table have 2 rows but I have tried and failed, how to create in a 2 row colum?

[likely this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7sJx.jpg)

I tried everything but could not, you can explain it to me
Thank a lot

```html
<table id="items">
        <tr>
            <th width="25%">Prestation</th>
            <th width="10%">Prix Unitaire</th>
            <th width="10%">Quantity</th>
            <th width="10%">Montant</th>
            <th width="45%">Condition</th>
        </tr>

        <tr class="item-row">
            <td class="item-name">
                <div class="delete-wpr"><input type="text" style="width: px; height: 47px;"><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div>
            </td>

            <td><input type="text" class="cost" style="width: 100px; height: 47px;"></td>

            <td><input type="text" class="qty" style="width: 60px; height: 47px;"></td>
            <td><span class="price"></span></td>

            <tr class="condition">
            </tr>

            <tr id="hiderow">
                <td colspan="5"><a id="addrow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row">Add a row</a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="1" class="blank"> </td>
                <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Subtotal</td>
                <td class="total-value">
                    <div id="subtotal"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td colspan="1" class="blank"> </td>
                <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Total</td>
                <td class="total-value">
                    <div id="total"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1" class="blank"> </td>
                <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Montant payé</td>

                <td class="total-value"><input type="text" id="paid" style="width: 50px; heigth: ;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1" class="blank"> </td>
                <td colspan="2" class="total-line balance">Solde dû</td>
                <td class="total-value balance">
                    <div class="due"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think you need `rowspan` https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_td_rowspan.asp

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your question. If you mean, have one column in 2 row, try use `rowspan="2"` in tag `<row>` instead of `colspan`.

- `Colspan` will stretch one column through columns.
- `Rowspan` will
  stretch one row through rows.

Comment: can you look my image and you wil understand my question, sorry a bout my question

Comment: I looked at you picture, but I don´t understand. What the red crosses means?

Comment: That's the part I want you to help me, the parts I have not done

Comment: okey, I see. Just use colspan and rowspan for making matrix you want and if you need some more styling, just make one of the border with opacity 0, or same backgroundcolor or something else.

Comment: so, you can demo for me plz, because i'm just start study web, tank a lot